# jquery execute something when 2 function have ended?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 functions

```
function f1() {
}
function f2() {
}
```

I want to call fend() when f1() and f2() have finished

**I am looking for a "clean" solution related whith .when or promise function.**

Comment: what is in that f1 and f2 function?

Comment: Depends if f1 and f2 do something asynchronous.

Comment: I mean, you can just do `f1(); f2(); fend();` but i'm assuming you want it asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use [deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and resolve them. Use [jQuery when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to trigger callback once both deferred have been resolved.

https://jsfiddle.net/v9o7ry8a/2/

```
var f1 = function() {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        // A pretend async call
        setTimeout(function() {
            d.resolve();
        }, 1000);

        return d;
    },
    f2 = function() {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        d.resolve(); // This function resolves right away but f1 takes a second!
        return d;
    };

$.when(f1(), f2()).done(function() {
    // This is your 'fend' function
    alert('hi');
});
```

You should also handle failures etc if they are possible to occur. You can also call `.resolve` with arguments if you wish to access data from `f1` or `f2` in your `fend` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can do:

```
var state = 0;
function f1() {
    //Do something
    state++;
    fend();
}
function f2() {
    //Do something
    state++;
    fend();
}
function fend() {
    if (state == 2) {
        console.log("fend called");
        state = 0; //reset the state value
    }
}
```

Increment a var when each function end, then call fend(). If the state is 2, that means the 2 functions have been executed.

JSFIDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/tzr4kp4r/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this :

```
var check = false;
function f1(){
if(check == true)
fend();
else
check = true;
}

function f2(){
if(check == true)
fend();
else
check = true;
}
```

When both function first function will be finished, check will be true . 
When the second finished, fend will be called.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This isn't limited to jQuery, it's just JavaScript but you can test a boolean each time. At the end of either function the boolean will be set to true:

```
var didEitherFunctionFinish = false;

function f1() {
    // f1()'s logic goes here

    if(didEitherFunctionFinish) {
        finalFunction();
    }

    didEitherFunctionFinish = true;
}

function f2() {
    // f2()'s logic goes here

    if(didEitherFunctionFinish) {
        finalFunction();
    }

    didEitherFunctionFinish = true;
}

function finalFunction() {
    // what happens after both f1() and f2() have been called
}
```

The boolean starts out as false. At the end of either f1() or f2(), it's set to true no matter what. Prior to that happening a test is run to see if either function has finished yet. If they have, finalFunction() is then called.